# Change input date format for all devices

Tags: date, asp.net-core, format, date-formatting

how I can change to "DD/MM/YYYY" date format for all devices.

```
public class ClassA
{
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? Bdate { get; set; }
}

<input type="date" asp-for="@Model.Bdate">
```

output : 24-Nov-2021
this is right in my computer , but not right in other computers and output : "11/24/2021".

Comment: What do you mean *all devices*? I hope that doesn’t include my PC? :-) Also in what language are you coding? Please add relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the format you run out is MM/dd/yyyy, and I run it locally in 11/24/2021 style. You check your windows time setting to see if the dd/MM/yyy format is set, and you want to use it This format can be formatted like this:

[image]